# Does anyone know how to match a ProfileScreen image with a Drawer Navigation image? React Native

Tags: react-native

I have created a navigation drawer that has an image and a profile screen that has an image picker, however my images need to be manually loaded so they look the same. How can I upload my profile screen image and my navigation drawer image becomes updated automatically? I would appreciate any help (videos, links, share code etc.) Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issue you can do something like this

```
async componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    let user_id = await getuserinfo(this)
    if (user_id) {
      this.setState({
        user_id: user_id
      }, () => {
        this.getUserDetails()
      })

    } else {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('login')
    }
  }
```

whenever the props has changed you can update the drawer details by calling the data in the drawer.

Comment: Thank you Husain, I will give it a short and revert soonest